# Piping into commander.js

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface, git-bash

I noticed it's not possible (out of the box) to pipe into a CLI-tool setup with commander.js.
So I tried it as given in this post in a discussion on github: https://github.com/tj/commander.js/issues/137#issuecomment-50937953

But it didn't work for me. From what I see it seems like it is waiting for an "end"-signal, which doesn't happen, so i have to ctrl + c it.

And the post is from 2014. Is there a more up-to-date (working) way to achieve this?

(i'm using git-bash)